# How to execute youtube-dl from Java

Tags: java, youtube-dl

I've tried executing youtube-dl from Java using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("youtube.dl url") but I've quickly realised its a lot more complicated! There are several programs on github where coders are developing programs to execute youtube-dl from Java, which would be the best for me to go with? Any help or advice would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: what's your purpose of using youtube-dl? to download youtube videos?

Comment: I've built software to transcribe mp4s. I need to download the video, or even better the audio of the video, to send transcribe and then delete

Comment: Even though it would probably be a big dependency, check out lavaplayer, specifically https://github.com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer/tree/master/main/src/main/java/com/sedmelluq/discord/lavaplayer/source/youtube

Answer (score 3):

It's worth mentioning the `yt-dlp` Github project, a high-performance version of `youtube-dl`, with more parseable output.  Its command-line interface is almost the same as `youtube-dl`, but differs slightly to make small improvements/fixes.

`yt-dlp` downloads **much** faster than `youtube-dl`.  I found both easy to use directly via Java's ProcessBuilder.  Here's an example of downloading the audio from a YouTube video (requires `ffmpeg` on the PATH):

```
ProcessBuilder.command (
    "yt-dlp", // also works with "youtube-dl"
    "--extract-audio",
    "--audio-format", "mp3",
    "--audio-quality", "0",
    "--output", "myDirectory/%(title)s_%(id)s.mp3",
    myYoutubeUrl
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `youtubedl-java` Github project might work for you.  As of Dec 2021, it looks abandoned, but the lastest version works for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.sapher</groupId>
    <artifactId>youtubedl-java</artifactId>
    <!-- latests release version -->
    <!-- version>1.1</version -->
    <version>2cbe41f</version> <!-- i use latest commit to get callback interface class -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Users\\Nico\" && youtube-dl");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e ) {

}
```